# Why 13596*0.1 is different than 13596/10?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

I just stumble accross something really odd in Javascript.

My script was multiplying 13596 by 0.1, and the output was : `1359.6000000000001`

We can agree that 0.1 = 1/10, so I tried it :

```
13596/10 = 1359.6
```

I tested it with Firefox and Chrome, the same results occurs.

I wondered if it was related to floating, so I tried the following :

```
13596 * parseFloat(0.1) = 1359.6000000000001
```

Nope.

By the way, this is not equal :

```
(13596*0.1) === (13596/10) => false
```

Does anyone has an idea about this result ?

([Here's the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/1ds08p35/))

Comment: Because `0.1` is not one tenth (type `(0.1).toFixed(20)` in the console).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Hum. What? :p So what to do ? Divide by 10 (not multiply by 0.1 ?)

Comment: No, produce output to a certain precision using `toFixed`.

Comment: In that case, `(0.1).toFixed(1)`, right ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that, with floating points, a number you see on-screen is not necessarily *exactly* the number the computer is modelling.

For example, using `node`:

```
> 1359.6
1359.6
> (1359.6).toFixed(20)
'1359.59999999999990905053'
```

Node shows you `1359.6`, but when you ask for more precision, you can see that the real number is not exactly what you saw -- it was rounded. The same is true of 0.1:

```
> (0.1).toFixed(20)
'0.10000000000000000555'
```

Generally when you work with floats you accept this imprecision and round numbers before displaying them.

Some numbers *are* exactly representable, but it's safest to assume that floating point is imprecise. For example, 0.5 can be represented exactly:

```
> (0.5).toFixed(20)
'0.50000000000000000000'
```

Dividing by 10 actually produces the same result as multiplying by 0.1:

```
> 13596/10
1359.6
> (13596/10).toFixed(20)
'1359.59999999999990905053'
```

In other languages division between integers results in an integer, however in JavaScript all numbers are modelled as floating points.

Generally whenever you need to precisely represent decimal numbers you should use a decimal number type, though this is not available natively in JavaScript.

Also there is no point to use the code `parseFloat(0.1)` as `0.1` is already a float.

Comment: This dances around the core of the problem here, which is that `0.1` isn't exactly representable.  I think you can turn this into an excellent answer with a little more work.

Comment: @tmyklebu, I extended the answer a little to emphasise the point with some more examples.